# Backbone.js providing global el vs passing it in object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to learn Backbone.js and I am confused with the passing the el into the object of the view or creating a global variable.
What I mean to say is:

```
var CarsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    render: function(){
        var self=this;
        this.model.each(function(car){
            var carView = new CarView({ model:car });
            self.$el.append(carView.render().$el)
        });
        return this;
    }
});

var cars = new Cars([
    new Car({ id: 1, registrationNumber: "XLI887"}),
    new Car({ id: 2, registrationNumber: "ZNP123"}),
    new Car({ id: 3, registrationNumber: "XUV456"})
]);

var carsView = new CarsView({ el:"#container", model: cars });
```

When I do this, the `<ul>` is not created and I have to change my container tag to `<ul>`.
So I get this:

```
<div id="songs">
  <li id="1">Blue in Green</li>
  <li id="2">So what </li>
  <li id="3">All blues</li>
</div>
```

However if I do:

```
var CarsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "ul",
        render: function(){
            var self=this;
            this.model.each(function(car){
                var carView = new CarView({ model:car });
                self.$el.append(carView.render().$el)
            });
            return this;
        }
    });

var cars = new Cars([
    new Car({ id: 1, registrationNumber: "XLI887"}),
    new Car({ id: 2, registrationNumber: "ZNP123"}),
    new Car({ id: 3, registrationNumber: "XUV456"})
]);
var carsView = new CarsView({ model:cars });
$("#container").html(carsView.render().$el);
```

On inspecting element I get this:

```
<div id="container">
 <ul>
    <li id="1">XLI887<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="2">ZNP123<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="3">XUV456<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here is mt CarView:

```
var CarView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.model.get("registrationNumber"));
        this.$el.append("<button>Delete</button>");
        this.$el.attr("id", this.model.id);
        return this;
    }
});
```

On one side I am getting the  in the container tag and on the other hand I am not. I thought it might by due to the passing of the el as a global instead of in the view object but that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass option `el` like `{ el:"#container"}` you are telling backbone that the Root element of this view instance is an existing element in `DOM`, so backbone won't create a root element.

When you don't pass `el` option, backbone will create a Root element for you (in memory, not yet in DOM), which is when it respects other options like `tagName: "ul",` for customising the element it will be creating for you.

Imo the second method will save you from a lot of typical bugs so you should go that way, unless you really really want to give behaviour to an existing element in DOM, like server rendered content.

---

Some small improvements:

```js
var CarsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "ul",
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(car) {
      var carView = new CarView({
        model: car
      });
      this.$el.append(carView.render().$el)
    }, this);
    return this;
  }
});

var cars = new Cars([{
  id: 1,
  registrationNumber: "XLI887"
},
{
  id: 2,
  registrationNumber: "ZNP123"
},
{
  id: 3,
  registrationNumber: "XUV456"
}]);

var carsView = new CarsView({
  collection: cars
});

$("#container").html(carsView.render().$el);
```

Comment: That was a really good insight on the working of Backbone. Yeah, the second option makes a lot of sense. I’ll use that. Thanks a lot :)